# capistrano-bower can't find node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bower

I'm using bower and now need to deploy it on my servers.
These are the relevant bits of my capistrano deploy.rb:

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'braint'
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.3@braint'
set :nvm_map_bins,  %w{npm node bower}
set :nvm_node,      'v6.0.0'

set :bower_target_path, "#{release_path}"
```

And this is how the deploy fails:

```
DEBUG [684affc8] Finished in 0.035 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [e5982f6c] Running /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/bower install --quiet --config.interactive=false on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [e5982f6c] Command: cd /home/deployer/apps/braint/current && ( export NODE_VERSION="v6.0.0" ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/bower install --quiet --config.interactive=false )
DEBUG [e5982f6c]    /usr/bin/env: node
DEBUG [e5982f6c]    : No such file or directory
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: /usr/local/bin/bower exit status: 127
/usr/local/bin/bower stdout: Nothing written
/usr/local/bin/bower stderr: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: /usr/local/bin/bower exit status: 127
/usr/local/bin/bower stdout: Nothing written
/usr/local/bin/bower stderr: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bower:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: /usr/local/bin/bower exit status: 127
/usr/local/bin/bower stdout: Nothing written
/usr/local/bin/bower stderr: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

If I cut and paste the very same command on an interactive SSH session it doesn't return any error, which is very weird...

Could it be that it's not loading nvm because it's a non-interactive shell? How can I solve this?